# XML parsing in php : Simple_xml_loadfile function runs forever

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am having a problem with parsing an API which was working fine till yesterday!

The code snippet :

```
$checkurl = "http://api1.webpurify.com/services/rest/?method=webpurify.live.check&api_key=&text=".urlencode('test test test');

$response = simplexml_load_file($checkurl,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

The problem is `simplexml_load_file()` is not returning any value and loads forever!

Comment: Did you try to simply download the file and load it from a local file rather than remotely?

Comment: No Michael. Can you guide me through the process? Just surprised because this was working fine till yesterday and nothing as changed in the code as well.

Comment: Just open the url in your browser and see if you get what you expect. If it is taking forever to load ( and probably eventually timing out) it is possible that your packets are being dropped either by your server's outbound firewall, or the XML file's server's inbound firewall.

Comment: Yep. It loads fine in the browser. Thanks Mike! will check that! :)

Comment: lol will change the API key soon :)

Comment: URL and response are valid. Try to open socket connection for timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a SimpleXML problem, but most likely occurs because the download is being blocked somehow.

Open up your browser and try to access the URL first; if you can download the file properly, save it and run it through SimpleXML again. That would eliminate at least one factor.

Comment: +1.  The example code runs in my environment without issue, suggesting the issue is network related.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Will check with my server administrator.